# Nginx - Reacting to Upstream Response

Tags: nginx, lua, reverse-proxy, openresty

I am using nginx as reverse proxy for file storage upload with an external provider. 
When I am processing a file upload, I need to keep track (in my database) whether an upload was successful before returning the response to the user. I would therefore like to use the `ngx.location.capture` method provided in the lua-nginx-module to talk to my backend about the outcome of the request. Since I need to wait for the response of the upstream server I can only issue the capture in `header_filter_by_lua`. Unluckily I cannot issue any outwards communication in `header_filter_by_lua`. `ngx.location.capture`, `ngx.socket.*` and `ngx.exec` are only available when the response has not yet arrived.

How can I react to an upstream response in nginx?

Other approaches I've thought about:

- Have a script watch the access log and then issue a curl request. (Seems like there should be an easier way)
- Initially send the file via ngx.location.capture in content_by_lua (I don't think this would handle up to 5 GB filesize)

Help is appreciated :)

Comment: I went around this limitation by using `os.execute("curl [...]")` This feels plain wrong but works. Watch out about passing user generated input into the shell!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use for `/upload` location:
`content_by_lua_file` with `resty.upload` [module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-upload)

Comment: good suggestion. This alone wouldn't allow me to fully send the request body upstream, but I found [lua-resty-http](https://github.com/pintsized/lua-resty-http) which should enable large uploads. This way I can also define my response to the client more gradually and programmatically in Lua.

Comment: @user2474697 , this is good way, but remember it has got some https problems involved. I haven't found a solution to detect correct sequre keys.